# Sweave & Lyx fig=T in Sweave

Tags: r, ubuntu, latex, sweave, lyx

I'm following Gregor Gorjanc's [tutorial on LyX & Sweave](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7257209/Using-Sweave-with-LyX). Using Ubuntu 10.04 and `LyX` version 1.6.5 with all of `texlive-full` installed.

`R` scraps which result in numerical output produce a valid PDF.

But, when I try to compile simple figures like

```
<<chunk, fig=T>>=       [ctrl+enter]
hist(rnorm(100))        [ctrl+enter]
@
```

I get cryptic errors. Either that `chunk.temp.Rnw` wasn't found, or that `LaTeX` encountered an error and I should hit `<enter>` to ignore.

If I change `fig` to `figure` and `T` to `TRUE`, then the `LyX` document compiles but displays no graphics. With `pgfsweave` I get [this error](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pgf.user/3370), or sometimes [this one](http://old.nabble.com/latex-error-:-%22I-can%27t-find-file-%60tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex%27%22-td28536805.html).

Am I working with the wrong versions of these programs? Is there a way to elicit better error messages? Can I somehow dive into the LaTeX prompt and hit `<enter>` myself?

**update:** I [*was*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27993/can-i-download-ctan-packages-from-the-command-line-ubuntu/28004) using the wrong version of `LaTeX`; Ubuntu's default is too old. Also I needed to update to `LyX 2.0.1` and a newer version of `pgf` and `pgfSweave` (the programs are distinct).

The new (nondescript) error message is: `An error occurred while running: Rscript '/home/mars/.lyx/scripts/lyx-sweave-exec.R' 'UTF-8' 'pgfSweave' "/home/mars/" "/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.T1663/lyx_tmpbuf2/" "test.sweave.lyx.Rnw" > "test.sweave.Rnw".log 2>&1`

Comment: Your code works for me using LyX 2.0.0 and the Sweave module. I get a PDF with a histogram. Can you upgrade to 2.0? I'm not sure if it's available on Ubuntu (and don't have access to an Ubuntu machine at the moment).

Comment: @Kevin Thanks for trying it. Let me see if I can find Lyx 2.0. I thought that was "experimental" based on yihui xie's blog.

Comment: Actually 2.0.1 was just released, so LyX 2 is pretty stable. If I am reading this page: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lyx correctly, then Lucid is still on 1.6.

Comment: @Kevin Does that mean I should *not* build 2.0 from source?

Comment: Not at all. It's just easier to install from a package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27993/can-i-download-ctan-packages-from-the-command-line-ubuntu/27994#27994 there is a perennial problem with `TeX` in Ubuntu: their packages are way behind. Since many innovations with `Sweave` have happened in 2010-2011, it seems one must download and install an `.iso` from http://ftp.ctex.org/mirrors/CTAN/systems/texlive/Images/ rather than use `Synaptic`. So much for package management!

I'll accept my own answer only if this actually works.

**update:** Make sure you [disregard anything you read about Noweb.sty](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.editors.lyx.general/69816) because in `LyX 2.0.1` there is a "Sweave Module" meaning you should just use regular document classes (`article`, `book`, `report`) -- the `scraps` are replaced by `chunks` and essentially `Sweave` is handled natively. Also [disregard Brett Collier's lucid explanation](http://ggorjan.blogspot.com/2010/01/lyx-sweave-on-ubuntu-karmic.html) of how to install `LyX` because it's now outdated, despite Gregor Gorjanc's highly-googleable [blog post](http://ggorjan.blogspot.com/2010/01/lyx-sweave-on-ubuntu-karmic.html) saying it works. That is also outdated, or maybe it only works in Ubuntu 9 and not Ubuntu 10.04.

So the steps to successfully getting `Sweave` to work in `LyX` for Ubuntu 10.04 as of August 2011 are:

1. Get the newest `texlive` from tug.org -- not the one from Synaptic. How to do that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27993/can-i-download-ctan-packages-from-the-command-line-ubuntu/27994
2. Get `pgf` and `kTikz` as described here: http://justbloodywork.blogspot.com/2011/07/installing-latex-and-pgf.html
3. Follow Yihue's instructions here: http://yihui.name/en/2010/10/how-to-start-using-pgfsweave-in-lyx-in-one-minute/#comment-10929. Build `lyx-devel` from source, apply Yihue's patch, and configure some LyX preferences.
4. `Tools > Reconfigure` `LyX`.
5. Pray.
6. Start `LyX` and load Yihue's test file from (3). Hit `Ctrl + R`, not `Ctrl + D` to view.